# Set different inputVerifier for JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield, inputverifier

Here i set InputVerifier to my text field (`tf1`) :

```
public class MyInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {
@Override
public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
    String text = ((JTextField) input).getText().trim();
    if (text.isEmpty()) return false;
    if (text.matches(".*\\d.*")) return false;

    return true;
}

public static class Tester extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextField tf1,tf2;
    JButton okBtn;

    public Tester() {
        add(panel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Tester();
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        okBtn = new JButton("Ok");
        okBtn.addActionListener(this);
        tf1 = new JTextField(10);
        tf2 = new JTextField(10);
        tf1.setInputVerifier(new MyInputVerifier());
        tf2.setInputVerifier(new MyInputVerifier());
        panel.add(tf1);
        panel.add(tf2);
        panel.add(okBtn);
        return panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        MyInputVerifier inputVerifier = new MyInputVerifier();
        if (e.getSource() == okBtn) {
            if (inputVerifier.verify(tf1)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "True Value");
            }
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "False Value");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now i want to set input verifier to my second text field (`tf2`) , But my `tf2` verifier condition is different than `tf1`.

For example my `verify()` of `tf2` should be like:

```
@Override
public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
    String text = ((JTextField) input).getText().trim();
    if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Me")) return true;
    return true;
}
```

And so on for more text fields.

How to verify two or more text fields with different conditions with one extended class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to verify two or more text fields with different conditions with one extended class?**

You need to identify JTextField with a name:

```
JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
jTextField.setName("tf1");
```

And then use it like ths:

```
   public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        String name = input.getName();

        if(name.equals("tf1"))
        {
            String text = ((JTextField) input).getText().trim();
            if (text.isEmpty()) return false;
            if (text.matches(".*\\d.*")) return false;
        }
        if(name.equals("tf2"))
        {
            //other condition
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

In addition I think you need to check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html):

> The purpose of this class is to help clients support smooth focus
>   navigation through GUIs with text fields

Comment: My action performed() is a test for me, And nothing else

Comment: Why remove example link?!

Comment: What example? I did not get this

Comment: Yes, it was useful, But i want see more solutions, if available.